# EVGA Geforce GTX 760 ACX Installation issues

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I recently purchased a new Geforce gtx 760 from EVGA with ACX cooling, and I'm quite confused with the power supply.

The card came with 2 PCI connectors, however one was a 6-pin and the other was an 8-pin. What confused me though was that at the end of the 6-pin there were two 3-pin connectors (there were 4 slots for a pin on each connector, but only 3 of those slots per connector actually had pins). At the end of the 8-pin, there were 2 6-pin connectors.

How many of these need to be connected to the power supply?

The single ends are the ones that connect to the card. Here are some pictures of what the cords looked like:

This is the 6-pin with two 3-pin connectors:
[image: 4-Pin Molex to PCI-Express Power Connector]

This is the 8-pin with the two 6-pin connectors:
[image: 8-pin PCIe power connector]

Answer (score 1):

The 6-pin connects to two [Molex connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Molex_connector&oldid=573075867#Disk_drive_connector_.28Molex_8981_Series_Power_Connector.29).

The 8-pin connects to the PCIe power connectors.

I'm guessing the Molex connectors are missing the +5V rail and only using the +12V one (first wire). The two middle wires two are [ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity)). Super User [Hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes) points out [in the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/650879/evga-geforce-gtx-760-acx-installation-issues#comment1338364_650899) that these PCIe GPUs do not use need the +5V rail, so this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah, but I think i'm just going to completely avoid all those converters and just connect it straight to a 6-pin and an 8-pin, instead of going to all the trouble of using the molex. Would this be ok?

Comment: @Savas Absolutely. Those come for lower-end PSUs that don't have all the PCIe connections.

Comment: lol it turns out that I dont have an 8-pin connector, so it looks like ill have to use the molex connectors. My bad.

Comment: @Savas The fun level should be the same :)

Comment: +1. Those 6 and 8 pins connectors do feed +12v. Molex has +5 and +12. Since the card only needs the extra +12 there is no need to spent metal on the +5v pins.